# Rebasing the branch at fork to upstream master

Tags: git, rebase

```
Igor@fordanwork MINGW64 /c/wxFork
 git pull --rebase upstream master
remote: Enumerating objects: 962, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (664/664), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (153/153), done.
remote: Total 962 (delta 521), reused 616 (delta 510), pack-reused 298R
Receiving objects: 100% (962/962), 767.88 KiB | 3.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (614/614), completed with 128 local objects.
From https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxwidgets
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   44a5cf78d1..e2aca9cbd5  master     -> upstream/master
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>]
[<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<bran
ch>]
   or: git rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo

Available options are
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Why it doesn't want to rebase?

I am on my branch and I want to rebase this branch on the upstream master.

Splitting the commands doesn't help:

```
Igor@fordanwork MINGW64 /c/wxFork
 git fetch upstream
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 8), reused 8 (delta 8), pack-reused 2
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
From https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxwidgets
   e2aca9cbd5..cfdd4127b5  master     -> upstream/master

Igor@fordanwork MINGW64 /c/wxFork
 git rebase upstream/master
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>]
[<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<bran
ch>]
   or: git rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo

Available options are
    -v, --verbose         display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -q, --quiet           be quiet. implies --no-stat
    --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after
    --fork-point          use 'merge-base --fork-point' to refine upstream
    --onto ...            rebase onto given branch instead of upstream
    -r, --rebase-merges[=...]
                          try to rebase merges instead of skipping them
    -p, --preserve-merges
                          try to recreate merges instead of ignoring them
    -s, --strategy ...    use the given merge strategy
    --no-ff               cherry-pick all commits, even if unchanged
    -m, --merge           use merging strategies to rebase
    -i, --interactive     let the user edit the list of commits to rebase
    -x, --exec ...        add exec lines after each commit of the editable list
    -k, --keep-empty      preserve empty commits during rebase
    --allow-empty-message
                          allow rebasing commits with empty messages
    -f, --force-rebase    force rebase even if branch is up to date
    -X, --strategy-option ...
                          pass the argument through to the merge strategy
    --stat                display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -n, --no-stat         do not show diffstat of what changed upstream
    --verify              allow pre-rebase hook to run
    --rerere-autoupdate   allow rerere to update index with resolved conflicts
    --root                rebase all reachable commits up to the root(s)
    --autosquash          move commits that begin with squash!/fixup! under -i
    --committer-date-is-author-date
                          passed to 'git am'
    --ignore-date         passed to 'git am'
    --signoff             passed to 'git am'
    --whitespace ...      passed to 'git apply'
    --ignore-whitespace   passed to 'git apply'
    -C ...                passed to 'git apply'
    -S, --gpg-sign[=...]  GPG-sign commits

Actions:
    --continue            continue
    --abort               abort and check out the original branch
    --skip                skip current patch and continue
    --edit-todo           edit the todo list during an interactive rebase
    --quit                abort but keep HEAD where it is
    --show-current-patch  show the patch file being applied or merge
```

Comment: Do you have any alias set for "pull" or "rebase" which might be silently adding conflicting options?

Comment: @IMSoP GIt [doesn't allow](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias) to override existing commands: "*To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored.*"

Comment: @phd Ah, I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @IMSoP,, no aliases set to anything.

Comment: @GaëlJ, please see the edit. Running `git --version` yields `git version-2.18.0.windows.1`

Comment: Very odd—seems like you have a broken Git installation. I'm not aware of particular bugs in 2.18.0.windows.1, but the current Windows Git is 2.33 or so; upgrading might fix it, perhaps.

Comment: @torek, upgrading fixed it. But it is very odd indeed. Lets hope I don't need to redo the key thing in order to push.... BTW, I upvoted your answer. Thx.

Comment: Technically, that's just a comment, not an answer. The root of the problem remains undetermined, so I'm reluctant to put that in *as* an answer...

Comment: @torek, yes. That's why I didn't ask you to put it as answer and just upvoted the comment here `"as helpful"`.